# hasChildNodes is not a function tiny mice editor js error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, tinymce

I am using the tiny mice editor in my application but it's giving js error some times like

```
Uncaught TypeError: D.hasChildNodes is not a function
```

And I have checked the below links [Link1](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5263) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681051/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-haschildnodes-of-undefined) but it didn't work for me.

This error is coming in Firefox, Chrome and IE and the error js file it's showing editor_template.js. Please help me to solve this js error.

Comment: A link would be helpful. Maybe some resources are not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look using the CakePHP [Wysiwyg plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-wysiwyg) to load TinyMCE (or other WYSIWYG editors). It will take care of much of the setup and configuration, and makes loading TinyMCE as easy as:

```
echo $this->Wysiwyg->textarea('ModelName.fieldName', $inputOptions, $helperOptions);
```