# how to pass dom element to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I come from python background so spare me the criticism if this sounds silly. But I have three elements from the dom that I have stored in their separate variable and then made an array out of those variables.

```
var item = document.getElementById("s-tools");
var item2 = document.getElementById("s-tools2");
var item3 = document.getElementById("s-tools3");
var arr = [item, item2, item3]
```

Now I am trying to iterate over this array of dom objects in my for loop and remove child elements from these items.

```
 for (var item in arr) {
     while (item.hasChildNodes()) {
          item.removeChild(item.lastChild);
          }
     }
```

then it is throwing the following error and value in item is 0

> Uncaught TypeError: item.hasChildNodes is not a function

Comment: please share the html code.Also using `for .. in` is a bad idea for iterating an  array 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasChildNodes' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681051/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-haschildnodes-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems easier to do

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#s-tools, #s-tools2, #s-tools3').forEach( el => {
  while (el.firstChild) el.firstChild.remove();
});
```

```html
<div id="s-tools">
  <span>child 1</span>
</div>
<div id="s-tools2">
  <span>child 2</span>
  child 3
</div>
<div id="s-tools3">
  <div>child 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using for each loop, **item will be you key**. In array case item is array index of your array, and you trying to execution function **removeChild on array index that's why you getting the error**. You need to provide exact element for the function to execute

see the snippet.

```js
var item = document.getElementById("s-tools");
var item2 = document.getElementById("s-tools2");
var item3 = document.getElementById("s-tools3");
var arr = [item, item2, item3]

 for (var item in arr) {
     while (arr[item].hasChildNodes()) {
          arr[item].removeChild(arr[item].lastChild);
          }
     }
```

```html
<div id="s-tools">
  <p>para</p>
</div>
<div id="s-tools2"><p>para</p>
</div>
<div id="s-tools3"><p>para</p></div>
```

see below link for reference:" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

[For-each over an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks! I will accept the answer in 6 min!

Comment: but is there any other possibly more elegant way to do it?

Comment: yes there is, either you can use jquery $('element').empty(); if you wish to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

for...in loop doesn't iterates values. it iterates property names. 
try this.

```
for (var name in arr) {
    var item = arr[name];
    while (item.hasChildNodes()) 
        ....
```